# Angular - How do i use the Web Api Response while using @angular/http Reponse?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So i'm currently using Web Api Response for caching a response in a Service Worker's cache. For example:

```
caches.open('ppc-cache').then(function(cache) {
    if (response.ok) {
        const options = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        const jsonResponse = new Response(response.json(), options);

        return cache.put(url, jsonResponse);
    }
});
```

The cache.put requires the Web Api Response Interface.

And i'm using @angular/http's Response for mocking responses like so:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

mockBackend.connections.subscribe(( connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockRespond( new Response (new ResponseOptions({
        status: 200,
        body: "true"
    })));
});
```

connection.mockResponse requires the @angular/http's Response.

What can i do about this?

Edit:

As a work around, i created a new file called cache.mock.ts for the service worker code then just imported cache.mock.ts. Since cache.mock.ts doesn't import Response from @angular/http, it'll use the Web Api Response interface instead.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but does this help: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response?